# Why the arrow at the end of a straight line between nodes of a matrix disappears if it is followed by another line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

In the `tikzpicture` of the following MCE, each of the lines:

- between “a” and “b”,
- between “a” and “c”,

are ended by an arrow: so far, so good. But, as soon as the commented line is uncommented, there isn't any arrow at the end of the former. Why?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[-latex]
  \matrix (chart)
    [
      matrix of nodes,
      column sep      = 1cm,
      row sep         = 1cm,
    ]
    {
      a &   \\
      b & c \\
        & d \\
    };
  \draw
    (chart-1-1) -- (chart-2-1)
    (chart-1-1) edge (chart-2-2)
    % (chart-2-1) |- (chart-3-2) % <- uncomment in order to see the effect
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Illustration of the two cases

[image]
[image]

Comment: Arrow heads are only placed at the very end (or beginning) of a path. If you type `\draw (A) -- (B) (C) -- (D);` this is essentially only one single path, although it consists of two parts. You need to split up this into several paths, for example by using `\draw` multiple times.

Comment: In addition, an `edge` will be constructed as a separate path and since it inherits the `-latex`, it will draw arrow tips. It will not be part of the original path consisting *only* (!) of `(chart-1-1) -- (chart-2-1)` which will add an arrow tip at the end of that segment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[-latex]
  \matrix (chart)
    [
      matrix of nodes,
      column sep      = 1cm,
      row sep         = 1cm,
    ]
    {
      a &   \\
      b & c \\
        & d \\
    };
  \draw
    (chart-1-1) -- (chart-2-1)
    (chart-1-1) edge (chart-2-2);
  \draw
    (chart-2-1) |- (chart-3-2) % <- uncomment in order to see the effect
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: tikz chart]